# OpenStreetMap reverse geocoding zip codes?

Tags: web-services, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

I'm working on a blackberry application and would like to use the OpenStreetMap reverse geo-coding to get an address and/or a street corner. 
I found Nominatim but it doesn't seem to do zip codes in the US (it has UK postal codes though), is there a OpenStreetMap API to get zipcodes, or some other free/open licensed reverse geocoding or address to zipcode data/API

**note:** this is for a final school project(but as this is a API/data source question I feel its fair to ask)

**note2:** another person has already done a google maps version, I'm looking for something w/ a Creative Commons type license, please don't mention google maps
-be careful, I found at least one API that claims to be open but seems to be based around both OSM , google, and other data (ie, it didn't have the rights to give away to its data).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [Geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org). It offers different webservices around geocoding.

The [Postcode WS](http://www.geonames.org/postal-codes/postal-codes-us.html) will help you:
Postcode for Washington, USA:

- [Via HTML page](http://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html?q=Washington&country=US)
- [Via Webservice (XML response)](http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch?placename=Washington&maxRows=10&country=US)

There's a commercial offer but I don't know if the service is totally free. There's a limit of 3000 requests per day and ip.

Comment: Possible limit to service(but very high at 20,000/hour-I think), plus data is free(Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License)

Answer (score 3):

You can reverse-geocode US ZIP codes with [geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us/). [Their geocoder](http://search.cpan.org/~sderle/Geo-Coder-US/) is open source (GPLv2 or Perl Artistic License) and they encourage writing code using their web services API for non-commercial purposes. This is in fact the service [OpenStreetMap.org is using](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search#US_ZIP_Codes) for US ZIP codes.

Also have a look at [this overview of geocoders](https://webgis.usc.edu/Services/Geocode/About/GeocoderList.aspx).

Comment: This is a project for a company so this would not be too usefull, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @Roman A. Taycher: I have added an overview link that lists some geocoders. Some free services seem to allow commercial applications, but limited to a certain number of lookups per day.

Answer (score 1):

I found an opensource geocoder and have started to work on the autotooling. 
on extendthereach dot com slash products OpenSourceGeocoder

Here is my github, but it is not ready yet:
http://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/AutoToolsGeocoder

In theory we could use osm data with this, but I will have to look into it more.